# How to change positions of x and y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my real research world, it is very common to show x-axis on the top (or both top and bottom) and y-axis on the right. However, the default positions are x on the bottom and y on the left in ggplot2.

Following [Kohske Post Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2-dev/JkJU5CLBkQw), the commands used are:

```
x <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)
y <- sin(x * pi)
qplot(x, y, geom = "line") + 
scale_x_continuous(guide = guide_axis(position = "top")) + 
scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(position = "right"))
```

I have tried above commands in dev-mode:

```
install_packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
dev_mode()
install_github("ggplot2", "kohske", "feature/pguide")
library(ggplot2)
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work well with the latest `plyr` package. Messages:

```
The following 'from' values not present in 'x': col, color, pch, cex, lty, lwd, srt, adj, bg, fg, min, max... 
Error in plyr:::split_indices(seq_len(nrow(data)), scale_id, n)
```

Then I tried the [codes from github](https://github.com/kohske/ggplot2/blob/2167d1468fc71f91cba9e9e05805e81fc7b7a183/R/guide-axis.r) directedly, the messages are:

```
Error in continuous_scale(c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend", "xintercept"),  : 
  formal argument "guide" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I have noticed that Hadley said this functionality is on his to-do list. However, I could not find a solution at this moment. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 15):

From [`ggplot 2.2.0`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/11/14/ggplot2-2-2-0/) you can set the position of the axes with the `position` argument in `scale_`:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") + 
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**ggplot2 solution**

I adopt [This solution](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2) to create a right y axis.  Personally I find manipulating grobs using within a gtable really difficult. I give up with the x-axis but I give a lattice solution. I hope this functionality will be implemented in ggplot2 as soon as possible.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
dat <- data.frame(x<-seq(0, 10, 0.1),y = sin(x * pi))
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(colour = "blue") + theme_bw()
# extract gtable
g <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))

# axis tweaks
ia <- which(g$layout$name == "axis-l")
ax <- g$grobs[[ia]]$children[[2]]
ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.15, "cm")
pp <- c(subset(g$layout, name == "panel", select = t:r))
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g$widths[g$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <-  gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)
g$grobs[[ia]]$children[[2]] <- NULL
##############################
ia <- which(g$layout$name == "ylab")
ylab <- g$grobs[[ia]]
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g$widths[g$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <-  gtable_add_grob(g, ylab, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)
g$grobs[[ia]]$label = ''
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

**lattice solution**

This  is not a ggplot2 solution , but `lattice` one. Using `latticeExtra` with a ggplot2 theme we can get a similar look with the desired behavior.

```
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(y~ x, type='l', scales=list(x=list(alternating=2),
                                   y=list(alternating=2)),
       par.settings = ggplot2like(),axis=axis.grid)
```

[image]

Comment: “I hope this functionality will be implemented in ggplot2 as soon as possible” - could not agree more. And I also think the gtable method usage is rather difficult. Furthermore, is there any way to use "viewport" method (instead of grid.draw) to arrange several plots with right y axis?

Comment: @bearcat To arrange several plots it is better to use something like `library(gridExtra);grid.arrange(g,g)`. But try to use `Lattice` package, surely there is a learning curve , but it is a great package and well documented.

Comment: I believe "viewport" method has a better performance for specific usage - for instance, when trying to lay-out overlap sub-plots. Sorry, I am just waiting for more clear and easy-use solution.

Comment: this feature has been shot down https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/619#issuecomment-35941269