# Plotting level plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have 12 variables, ***M1, M2, ..., M12***, for which I compute a certain statistic ***x***.

```
 df = data.frame(model = paste("M", 1:28, sep = ""), x = runif(28, 1, 1.05))
 levels = seq(0.8, 1.2, 0.05)
```

I would like to plot this data as follows:

[image]

Each circle (contour) represents the a level of that statistic ***"x"***. The three blue lines simply represent three different scenarios. 
The dataframe included in this example represents one scenario. The blue line would simply join the values of all the models ***M1*** to ***M28*** for that specific scenario.

Is there any tool in R that allow for such a plot? I tried `contour()` from `library(MASS)` but the contours are not drawn as perfect circles.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're after some kind of a wind rose. Have you looked at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_polar.html?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, fyi, was already working on answer when you posted this (getting discrete variables to connect on line plots is a bit tricky), don't want you to think I just ran off with your suggestion.

Comment: Hehe @BrodieG, if I wanted to have credit for this, I would need to come up with my own answer. Blank shots in comments don't really count in my book. Good work on going the extra mile (kilometer where I come from) and providing an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a ggplot solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=model, y=x, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() + coord_polar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=range(levels), breaks=levels, labels=levels)
```

[image]

Note this is a little confusing because of the names in your data frame.  `x` is really the y variable here, and model the real `x`, so the graph scale label seems odd.

EDIT: I had to set your factor levels for `model` in the data frame so they plot in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!! Is there anyway I can customized where the level labels are located? I would rather have them in the middle of the plot, rather than on the far left...

Comment: @Mariam, this may not be possible (or easy).  See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334494/how-to-change-positions-of-x-and-y-axis-in-ggplot2).  One possible workaround is to use `geom_text()` to place the numbers where you want them, and then hide the actual axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That would actually work. Also, how did you do to set the factor levels in the dataframe?

Comment: @Mariam, just used `model = factor(paste("M", 1:28, sep = ""), levels=paste("M", 1:28, sep = ""))`

Comment: Amazing. I can't thank you enough! Sorry, last follow-up question: would it be possible to close the line, i.e. join M28 with M1?

Comment: @Mariam, you will need to add one extra point, which is just a repeat of the first, order your data so that point is last, and use `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()`, but I haven't tried it (diff between path and line is that for path, the order of the points matter).