# Place y-axis on the right

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I want to plot my data:

```
my.df <- data.frame(mean = c(0.045729661,0.030416531,0.043202944,0.025600973,0.040526913,0.046167044,0.029352414,0.021477789,0.027580529,0.017614864,0.020324659,0.027547972,0.0268722,0.030804717,0.021502093,0.008342398,0.02295506,0.022386184,0.030849534,0.017291356,0.030957321,0.01871551,0.016945678,0.014143042,0.026686185,0.020877973,0.028612298,0.013227244,0.010710895,0.024460647,0.03704981,0.019832982,0.031858501,0.022194059,0.030575241,0.024632496,0.040815748,0.025595652,0.023839083,0.026474704,0.033000706,0.044125751,0.02714219,0.025724641,0.020767752,0.026480009,0.016794441,0.00709195), std.dev = c(0.007455271,0.006120299,0.008243454,0.005552582,0.006871527,0.008920899,0.007137174,0.00582671,0.007439398,0.005265133,0.006180637,0.008312494,0.006628951,0.005956211,0.008532386,0.00613411,0.005741645,0.005876588,0.006640122,0.005339993,0.008842722,0.006246828,0.005532832,0.005594483,0.007268493,0.006634795,0.008287031,0.00588119,0.004479003,0.006333063,0.00803285,0.006226441,0.009681048,0.006457784,0.006045368,0.006293256,0.008062195,0.00857954,0.008160441,0.006830088,0.008095485,0.006665062,0.007437581,0.008599525,0.008242957,0.006379928,0.007168385,0.004643819), parent.origin = c("paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","maternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal","paternal"), group = c("F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:M","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1r:F","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:M","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F","F1i:F"), replicate = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

As follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = my.df, aes(factor(replicate), color = factor(parent.origin)))
p1 <- p1 + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(parent.origin),lower = mean - std.dev, upper = mean + std.dev, middle = mean, ymin = mean - 3*std.dev, ymax = mean + 3*std.dev), position = position_dodge(width = 0), width = 0.5, alpha = 0.5, stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 4)+scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue"),labels = c("maternal","paternal"),name = "parental allele")+scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"),labels = c("maternal","paternal"),name = "parental allele")
p1 <- p1 + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'), legend.position = "none")+theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill="white"))
```

This gives:

[image]

My question is how can I move the y-axis to be on the right side of the plot? I've seen several posts about it from the past but they seem rather hacky so I was wondering whether anyone knows of a new implementation that makes it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's still no easy way to do it. There's an [issue/feature request open on GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/619), but since moving to ggplot 1.0 and focusing on [ggvis](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/), it probably won't be taken care of any time soon. The [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334494/how-to-change-positions-of-x-and-y-axis-in-ggplot2), or [this example](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2) seem to be the only way to do it for now (and forever, probably).

Comment: You can do this in `ggvis` ala `add_axis("y", title = "Yo", orient = "right")` Of course it doesn't look like geom_boxplot is implemented yet: http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html

Answer (score 118):

With ggplot versions above 2.2.0, this should work:

```
scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
```

Comment: Can you get the same result with labs() or theme()?

Comment: Wondering about this as well in 2021.

Comment: @user1701545 Please consider changing your accepted answer to this

Answer (score 5):

The "cowplot" package with "ggdraw" function can help, as described there:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/axis_position.html

```
ggdraw(switch_axis_position(p1 + theme_gray(), axis = 'y'))
```

Comment: This sounds great! Yet, it does not work for facet plots: 'Can only switch axes on plots with exactly one panel.' Do you know of any tricks for facets?

Comment: @Thales West. I was also set on facets, however I now switched to arranging my plots using `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package and it has been working very well for me

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `scale_y_continuous` and `guides` to have y-axis on right side of graph:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Y-axis Label on right side")) +
  guides(y = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>