# How to flip a ggplot horizontally?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot spaghetti plot that currently looks like this:

[image: current ggplot]

I'd like to flip it on the x-axis (horizontally) so that it looks like this:

[image: desired ggplot]

But I cannot figure out how... coord_flip gives me this plot:

[image: unwanted ggplot]

which is not what I'm looking for.

how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527385/place-y-axis-on-the-right:   `scale_y_continuous(position = "right")`

Comment: When you say "flip"---do you actually want the mirrored image you show? Or do you want some or all of (a) reversing the order of the x axis, (b) moving the y-axis labels from the left side to the right side, (c) something else?

Comment: `scale_x_reverse()` can be used to reverse the x axis. That (maybe) together with Jon's link might be enough. If you need more help, I'd suggest sharing a small reproducible example data set and plot code so we have something to work with.

Comment: Yes, i want to a) reversing the order of the x axis, (b) moving the y-axis labels from the left side to the right side, with the mirror image of the current plot

Comment: When i use "scale_x_reverse", i get this error: Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: please share your code

Comment: *"Scale for 'x' is already present."*  is a warning, not an error. As for the error, have you tried to reverse the x axis by plotting the symmetric of its values? If so, then the error is saying what seems obvious from the posted plots, that `x` is a factor, not numeric, and `-x` is not defined for non-numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

I used my own data to simulate what you wanted. You should just need the last two lines of code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(55)
scatter_data <- tibble(x_var = runif(100, min = 0, max = 25)
             ,y_var = log2(x_var) + rnorm(100)
             )

p <- ggplot(data = scatter_data, aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) +
  geom_point()

p + scale_x_reverse(lim =c(25,0)) +
 scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
```

[image: Flipped plot]