# horizonl bar plot when y elements are on the left side

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How can I have a horizonl bar plot which y elements are on the left side of the plot not right side.

```
A <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear ,fill=gear))+ geom_bar() + 
theme(legend.position="none")+coord_flip()
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you would like the plot to look like, or include a mock up.

Comment: If you meen to change side of the axis then look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334494/how-to-change-positions-of-x-and-y-axis-in-ggplot2)